# css have another dropdown within a dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I have this piece of code

```
<li class="dropdown" runat="server" id="btn_logout">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user">USER</i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:black;">
    <li class="dropdown-header">DROPDOWN HERE: </li>
    <li><a href="#">Manage Account</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Sign Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I would like to have another dropdown where it says `drop down here`.
How can I do this?

Comment: You cannot do it with clicks, since clicking in the sub-dropdown will close the first one. But you can use CSS to open the sub-dropdowns when hovering on the desired element.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As you will see over time, SO is not about "asking for help, please". It's quite usual that we face doubts that we can't find an answer to it, and we can take advantage of communities like SO to help us out. What this community asks back is that you write good questions, if you want to get better at this, I recommend that you take a few time reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, submenus [are not supported](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21026#issuecomment-256704655) on bootstrap.

(TLDR) There are hacks as you may imagine:

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<li class="dropdown" runat="server" id="btn_logout">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user">USER</i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:black;">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">another level</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:black;">
        <li><a href="#">Manage Account</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Sign Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Manage Account</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Sign Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

[source](https://codepen.io/svnt/pen/beEgre?editors=1010)